# theano try except statements

Tags: python, theano

I wish to take the cholesky **if possible** in theano. For example:

`try:
    L = T.slinalg.cholesky(self.cov)
except:
    return -np.inf`

However, it seems that theano doesn't quite work with try catch statements since it chucks an error regardless. I'm using theano 0.9.0rc4 if it helps.

Comment: except, not catch

Comment: edited. I did mean `except`.